# Unable to show login messages when username is correct and password is wrong

Tags: express, passport.js, express-session

I have just started learning express. I am adding basic authentication using passport js. I have followed this [documentation](https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/password/). It is working a little bit odd on error messages. When the username is correct and password is wrong, it doesn't add any messages to session. It just has basic info like path.

```
    app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
      const user = new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
      });
    
      console.log(req.session);
      req.login(user,function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        else{
          passport.authenticate("local",{ failureRedirect: '/login', failureMessage: true })(req,res,function(){
            res.redirect("/secrets");
          });
        }
      });
    
    });
```

When the username is wrong, it adds message to session but it doesn't reload properly. it doesn't reload at all to "/login". I have to literally kill the process and then this session data is added.

It doesn't seem to work at all. Kindly help me with dealing both of errors, i.e. right username wrong password and wrong username wrong password.

Comment: What does `req.login` do?

Comment: It is used to establish a login session. The complete info can be found [here](https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/login/)

Comment: The documentation says: "Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically", and I assume it does so _after_ authenticating. But you call `req.login()` yourself _before_ calling `passport.authenticate()`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you use that `req.login` function correctly.
I think you are misunderstand between `login` and `authentication`

What you are thinking is `if login fail then authenticate again` while actually, you need to `authenticate user first, then login after`

So the flow, step by step will be:

1. Verify the user - whether this user entered a correct password or even exist in the system.
   This step called `authentication`
2. After you verified the user is what he/she claimed to be. You let the user `enter` your system. This called `login`

Here is the document you can follow to understand how passport work.
https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/downloads/html/ (As you are new to express, make sure you understand the `General` section thoroughly - `Middleware` and `Strategy` are key concepts)
https://www.passportjs.org/tutorials/password/ (this is a practical version of the above document)

Comment: Hey, yeah got it. I removed the login part as it was automatically authenticating. Could you help with how can I display the error message that I got in session info. How can I display that on screen after login fails ? In session there are error messages present but how can I display them on screen. ty.

Comment: You can just use as normal variable in template. In case you don't understand my previous statement, you should take a look at "express-session", see how to use it, then you can apply to this case